# Unable to open documents from SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a number of individuals (all from the same external group) who are unable to open documents from our extranet site, which is running SharePoint 2007. The exact error is:
No connectivity with the server.
The file "..." can't be opened because the server couldn't be contacted.

We're using Forms authentication for external users, however no one other than this group of individuals has been having issues thus far. I've gone through the doc library's settings (no special security, just the default, all docs are checked in, etc.), security for the site has been checked and they have access, I even checked the IIS settings, the MIME types, our firewall (which isn't blocking anything from what I can tell), and everything appears to be working well.

Since this is the only group that we've encountered this issue with, we're thinking it's a setting on their end (IE permissions, something locked down in Word, etc). However we do not have access to their machines, they wont let us change any of the settings, etc.

So all of that said, has anyone else run into this and if you fixed it, was it a server side fix? Or something on the user's machine? And what the heck was it, because I'm giving up on this one fairly soon.

Comment: What version of IE and Office are they using? There's *issues* with the latest versions. Also, is everything/anything run over SSL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had some similar issues like this with our current deployment. All of the users who experienced this sort of thing (they also had issues uploading via the upload form, but no issues uploading via WebDav) had a statically configured proxy server in IE that was causing issues. My bet would be it is a proxy server or some sort of security device on their end.

Comment: We found a way around it by using a simple FTP server, but in the mean time we were able to confirm that it was due to their setup (we couldn't get their IT staff to confirm what exactly, but they admitted it was on their end). The proxy server answer would make sense.